# Prove that sum of any two sides of a triangle is greater than twice the median with respect to the third side.

Tags: geometry, triangles, triangle-inequality

"Prove that sum of any two sides of a triangle is greater than twice the median with respect to the third side."

This question is from Mathematics NCERT Exemplar Class 9, exercise 7.4 , question number 10

In this question I only able to solve : AB + AC > 2AD,
If ABC is a triangle and D is a point on BC such that AD is the median .

I tried a lot but , but I didn't able to prove: AB + BC > 2AD and BC + AC > 2AD

https://byjus.com/ncert-exemplar-class-9-maths-chapter-7-triangles/

https://www.mathongo.com/ncert-exemplar/ncert-exemplar-for-class-9-maths-chapter-7

These websites and many other websites also proved: AB + AC > 2AD and say similarly you can prove : AB + BC > 2AD and BC + AC > 2AD

But I didn't able to solve these problems.

Comment: You're interpreting the statement incorrectly. The "with respect to the third side" changes as you change the "any two sides of a triangle". IE You have to show that $ AB+BC > 2 BE$. $\quad$ Otherwise, for an easy counterexample, take a really skinny isosceles triangle where $ AB \approx AD$ and $BC \approx 0$, then $ AB + BC < 2 AD$.